# Deserialize Json property name with space using wp8 inbuilt json classes

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8

I have a Json string which contains space in its property name. Now how I should do that.
I searched and found the following answer.

```
public jsonClass 
{
   [JsonProperty(Name="Space Property")]
   public string SpaceProperty {get; set; }
}
```

But it seems like I've to use json.net library to achieve this.

Is there a way that I can achieve the same thing with the use of wp8 inbuilt datacontract json serializer dll?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DataMemberAttribute` has a `Name` property.

```
[DataContract]
public jsonClass 
{
   [DataMember(Name = "Space Property")]
   public string SpaceProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;

DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(jsonClass )); 
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString)); 
jsonClass obj = (jsonClass )ser.ReadObject(stream);
```

Read here, how to deserialize without using Json.Net

[http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Json-Parsing-in-windows-74d89955](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx)

[Serialize and Deserialize JSON Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx)

Comment: I think i didn't make my question clear. I'm already using this method. BUt in my Json string I've a property name with space in it. So I need to know how to declare the object for that property.

Comment: what you have declared is the way to declare a property with space!

Comment: But I need json.net for this right ? Can I not do this with the inbuilt json classes itself ?